# Incompatible SSIS projects in VS 2022

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2022, incompatibletypeerror, sql-data-tools

My SSIS projects appears as incompatible in VS, so I can not run anything. I have returned to the last version (VS 2022 17.6.2).
Everything used to work fine until I updated the VS and after that all my SSIS projects are broken.

I checked the extension Data tools which was installed, so I uninstalled and reinstalled.
Furthermore I desabled and enabled the Sql Data Tools extensions, and updated the sql Data Tools, but nothing works.

Thx!

[Incompatibles solution and project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubsPp.png)
[Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRzXN.png)

I checked the extensions , and uninstalled and reinstalled the Sql Data Tools.
I disabled and enabled the same extension.
I changed into the last functional version of Vs (17.6.2)
Updated the sql data tools.
Tried to add directly nuget package , but VS showed me  I can not do anything because the format is not compatible.

[Incompatible error when I tried to check the nuget Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4EJI.png)

Comment: Was the package created with an older version of VS? When you upgrade to new major versions of VS, you often have to convert your SSIS packages/projects to the new format. I think that's what the error screen is saying, but I don't read Spanish. Try converting them to the new VS format and see if that works. Otherwise, it might be more helpful to post images of your errors in English, as that's the primary language used on this website.